# Windows phone null image error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a app for windows phone, which is basically includes phone contacts. I'm getting all the phone contacts using Contacts class and I'm storing contact data in the isolated storage. Since I cant serialize images, I'm converting them to byte[] before serializing. My code is:

```C#
foreach (var result in e.Results)
{
    if (result.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault() != null)
    {

        BitmapImage bmp2 = new BitmapImage();
        bmp2.SetSource(result.GetPicture());


        listobj.Add(new AddressBook()
           {
               FirstName = result.DisplayName ?? "",
               imageBytes = AddressBook.imageConvert(bmp2),
               EmailAddress = "",
               LastName = "",
               Phone = result.PhoneNumbers.FirstOrDefault().PhoneNumber ?? "",
           });
    }
}
```

When Contact has no picture it shows an Argument null exception error on the line:

```
bmp2.SetSource(result.GetPicture());
```

So when contact image is null I want to use some custom image ("/Images/ci2.png" or any Blank image would also work).
My xaml code is:

```XAML
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,2" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel Width="80" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="80">
        <Ellipse Margin="0" Height="70" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stroke="{x:Null}">
            <Ellipse.Fill>
                <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding imageByte, Converter={StaticResource BytesToImageConverter}}"/>
            </Ellipse.Fill>
        </Ellipse>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Height="80" Margin="0" Width="380" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding FirstName}" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phone}" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="24" Margin="5,0,0,-12" Width="320" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <TextBlock.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFCFC9C9"/>
            </TextBlock.Foreground></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

My question is, How can I use custom image when

```
 bmp2.SetSource(result.GetPicture());
```

is null? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems.

```
<Ellipse.Fill>
    <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="{Binding imageByte, Converter={StaticResource BytesToImageConverter}}"/>
</Ellipse.Fill>
```

You have a `{Binding imageByte}` but in the C# code you have

```
listobj.Add(new AddressBook()
{
    FirstName = result.DisplayName ?? "",
    imageBytes = AddressBook.imageConvert(bmp2),
    // ...
});
```

**imageBytes != imageByte**

Unless you're not showing the complete code.

Like the other poster said, set it from the resource file.  His code will cause an error because it includes an extra "/"  so change it to....

```
if (result.GetPicture() != null)
{
     bmp2.SetSource(result.GetPicture());
}
else
{
     bmp2.SetSource(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"Images/ci2.png", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
}
```

Comment: @Chubosaurus Software Thanks it worked but when I deployed it on my phone, it threw an error: "system.outofMemoryException"

Answer (score 5):

Looking at this quickly, couldn't you just do:

```
if (result.GetPicture() != null)
{
     bmp2.SetSource(result.GetPicture());
}
else
{
     bmp2.SetSource(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"Images/ci2.png", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
}
```

If not, I have implemented a different solution for this and can probably post some more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Above method didn't work, then I removed all your code except bmp2.SetSource(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"/Images/ci2.png", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
} .Still I'm getting the same error. Looks like this line has no effect at all. Anymore suggestions?

Comment: when I deployed it on my phone, it threw an error: "system.outofMemoryException" any idea?

Comment: Off the top of my head - could be your image converter code but I'd also check that ci2.png is deployed to the device and in the right location. What device are you using? Is it low-end?

Comment: Yes I'm using low-end device, may be thats why it works fine on my emulator but not on my phone. Is there any way to avoid this exception?

Comment: You need to find out what's causing it - it might be just some code is inefficient, such as your image converter, or it might not be able to find the image and craps out there. I have noticed it other times too, eg when uploading large files to a server.

Comment: A tip - get IsoStoreSpy to see what files are on the device: https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/

Comment: Also, how many items are returned in e.Results? And how big are the image files? Might be related to that.

Comment: I solved the issue by adding bmp2.Urisource=null at the end of my code. Thanks :)